# How the cores are used in Directstream approach

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have **1 kafka topic**, by using the direct stream approach in spark we have to processing the data present in topic , with one node R&D cluster for to understand how the Spark will behave.

My machine configuration is **4 Cores, 16 GB RAM with 1 executor**.

My question is how many cores are used for this job while running.

In web console it show 4 cores are used.

How the **cores are used in Directstream approach**? 
[image]
Command to run the Job :

**./spark/bin/spark-submit --master spark://XX.XX.XX.XXX:7077 --class org.eiq.IndexingClient ~/spark/lib/IndexingClient.jar**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- you have >= 4 Kafka partitions or more in your kafka server,
- and this is running with the Direct Kafka Connector,
- and this is running a in local mode on your single machine

Then all cores are used for computation : they retrieve the offsets from the topics they are suppose to read, and each reads those offsets and processes them in parallel.

If you have less than 4 Kafka partitions, of course this limits the parallelism of data ingestion you can get reading from Kafka correspondingly.

More on the Kafka direct approach here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers

Comment: I have one doubt, charan saying, he has 4 core and according to Spark doc, Streaming reserve one core for receiver so there are 3 free core for parallel processing.

Comment: That is true in the receiver mode. However, if he is using the Kafka *direct stream*, there is no receiver, and, all cores are available. Read the link I added for more details.

Comment: Thanks @huitseeker for more detail.